# Help in Reverting Nokia X RM-980 to STOCK ROM

Tags: custom-roms, stock-rom, nokia-x

I have a NOKIA X RM-980 mobile phone and I desired to install a custom ROM on it. I had choose Lovi OS 2.0 Update 1 (Unofficial-LoviOS-2.0pa.zip) + (TWRP-3.0.0-0-normandy-X.img) .

After that I decided to install Google Play (GApps_Minimal_4.4.4_signed .zip).

Problems:

1. After setting up Google Play with my account, it didn't worked! and
   many pre-installed apps became corrupt with an error message:
   "unfortunately com.google.process.gapps has stopped" .
2. WiFi is automatically powers every time I restart or power-up the
   phone.
3. Camera became not working with this error message: "unfortunately
   the process com.google.process.media has stopped" .
4. I backed-up some personal files by Moving them from SD card as a
   prepare step to install the stock ROM on this phone, but they are
   still appearing when I connect the phone to my PC ! and in the same
   time aren't exist at file manager on the phone ???
5. So, I decided to rollback to the original firmware - stock ROM - by
   following two methods:

(5a) Nokia Care Suite.

(5b) Nokia X Flasher.

(5c) ADB and Fastboot.

All are not working, after restart, system is restored again and again with the same status !

During this post, I tried to do something to prove my theory. I've change the desktop background on the phone and after restart, it revert back to the default one. Phone became in "read only" or "system restore" mode. that's why the stok ROM wouldn't install.

No important personal data on this phone, I'm free to totally format it.

Stock ROM info:

> Model : RM-980
>
> Variant : 059T9F2
>
> Revision : 1.2.4.1
>
> Manufacture : Microsoft
>
> Platform : Nokia X

Apart from that, let me share some issues that I found may it will help us to solve this problem.

To check the status of bootloader, I used this command:

```
fastboot oem device-info

Device tampered: false
Device unlocked: false
```

I used this command to unlock bootloader:

```
fastboot oem unlock

Device tampered: false
Device unlocked: true
```

Every time I reboot the device, it's resets automatically to locked state again.

```
Device tampered: false
Device unlocked: false
```

I think the main problem is that device is not writable. Any actions on this device was gone after every reboot.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this problem?

I really appreciate your supporting in this. I really need every help.